# Power BI count number of active stations at a location based

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables:

1. Times - All the hours between our data sets start and end date. This is what we are using to graph everything that is time-based.
2. Station History - All of the information for the station including when it went into service, and when it went out of service. The start and end dates link to the dates table, and the Location Name.

I am trying to count the number of terminals active at each location for each date but, so basically I need to look and see if the stations start and end state are outside of the date in the Times table. The problem is that I have been unable to link it to the location.

I have been able to count the total number of active stations by adding a column to the Times Table called ActiveStations and using:

```
CALCULATE(COUNTA(Stations[StationId]), FILTER(Stations, Stations[StationStartDate] <= [Date] && Station[StationEndDate] >= [Date]))
```

The problem is that I am unable to link this to the location.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Best to share what your two table look like (paste sample rows in [markdown table format](https://markdown-convert.com/en/tool/table), together with how they are related.